# What happens if I edit out a tag in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comment-replies

If I write a comment and tag someone (@username), they get a notification.  I can do this once per comment to prevent me from spamming a whole bunch of people (there was a post about that somewhere, but I can't find it).

Now, what would happen if I edit that tag out of the comment, and put in a tag to a different user? Does the first tag notification disappear? Does the second user get notified? Do I get scolded for working around the system?

Comment: I suspect @ tagging only works when the comment is first posted, not when it's edited.

Comment: MSE posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees

Comment: @AzizShaikh, Thanks for pointing those out, this question is a dupe, I'll delete it in a bit

Comment: @wnnmaw no, deletion is not required. Dupes across MSO and MSE are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would happen if I edit that tag out of the comment, and put in a tag to a different user?

**The other user will also get a notification**.

[Richard Tingle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/220332/richard-tingle) did a little experiment and reported the [observations on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197418/) as follows:

> If at any point @yourname was in a comment you will get a notification
>   in your inbox. But you will only get a red(1) notification if
>   @yourname is currently in the comment (either originally or by edit),
>   i.e. if @yourname is edited out and you haven't seen the red(1)
>   notification yet it is removed.